# Jquery click function same script

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

is there any way to execute diferente funcs for different elements on the same page?

```
$('.class1').click(function() {
   $.ajax({  url:'pages/page1.php?id1='+this.id, 
         success:function(data){
            $("#Loading").fadeOut('fast'); //hide when data's ready
            $("#homeContent").html(data);
         } });
});

$('.class2').click(function() {
   $.ajax({  url:'pages/page2.php?id2='+this.id, 
         success:function(data){
            $("#Loading").fadeOut('fast'); //hide when data's ready
            $("#homeContent").html(data);
         } });
});
```

Im using firebug, and when i do diferent clicks, it stack get requests, like this:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/pages/jemissoes.php?id=1 (1st click)
GET http://127.0.0.1/pages/jemissoes.php?id=2 (2nd click)
GET http://127.0.0.1/pages/jemissoes.php?id=2
GET http://127.0.0.1/pages/jemissoes.php?id=3 (3rd click)
GET http://127.0.0.1/pages/jemissoes.php?id=3
GET http://127.0.0.1/pages/jemissoes.php?id=3
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that what you are already doing in the first example?

Comment: Ive updated the code. Joao, It works proper on site, but at same time is wasting data as I see in firebug

Comment: Do you mean it's firing more times than expected? Your code looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: yes, its repeating it self , and stacking those GET requests as same as I do some click.

Comment: But what exactly do you want to do? If someone clicks the same `id` more than once, and there's already a sent `ajax` request, pending response, you want to stop this new one from being sent?

Comment: When someone clicks .class1 it loads some data in #homeContent:GET h*tp://127.0.0.1/pages/jemissoes.php?id=1. When someone clicks .class2 it loads some data in #homeContent: GET h*tp://127.0.0.1/pages/jemissoes.php?id=2
GET h*tp://127.0.0.1/pages/jemissoes.php?id=2
Why it doubles it self?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16453/discussion-between-user1148875-and-joao-silva)